# Which hydroxyl from either the phosphate or the glycerol is taken during synthesis of a phospholipid head?

Tags: biochemistry

The oxygen anion in the phosphate group is likely to be bonded with a hydrogen cation and thus forming a hydroxyl.

When the phosphate group is condensed with glycerol to make a phospholipid, is the hydroxyl from the glycerol molecule taken or the hydroxyl from the phosphate group taken?

I believe it's related to the difference of electronegativity of oxygen and phosphorus which causes unequal sharing of electrons between atoms, thus making a hydroxyl from one side easier to get taken off than the hydroxyl from the other side is.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out where in the process you are talking about.  Are you asking about the creation of Glucose 6-phosphate, phosphatidic acid, or phospholipids down stream of DAG?  I was originally thinking the creation of phosphatidic acid, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

In all phosphorylation reactions, the **oxygen** of the hydroxyl group in the **substrate** attacks `P` of phosphate. This is because of high partial positive charge on `P` which is bonded to four highly electronegative oxygen atoms. When the bond forms between the substrate oxygen atom and phosphorus of terminal phosphate, electrons are transferred to the `O` that bridges the ester bond between 2nd and 3rd phosphate. Therefore the `O` of the substrate is retained and that of the terminal phosphate (of ATP) becomes the part of the 2nd phosphate (now terminal phosphate of ADP).

[image]

See [this](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Organic_Chemistry/Organic_Chemistry_With_a_Biological_Emphasis/Chapter_10%3A_Phosphoryl_transfer_reactions/Section_10.2%3A_Phosphorylation_reactions_-_kinase_enzymes)

Answer (score 0):

My recollection is that the formation of a phospholipid normally involves acylation of glycerol 3-phosphate. Glycerol 3-phosphate is a glycolytic intermediate, and so there is no actual phosphorylation of a glycerol; the phosphate on the glycerol will have come from the phosphorylation of glucose or of fructose 6-phosphate.

In a kinase reaction the oxygen of the -OH in the acceptor acts as a nucleophile at the P of the phosphate, so in terms of your question the O atom comes from the acceptor, not the donor. Presumably if there was a glycerol kinase (I expect there is) it would have the same mechanism so the O would come from the glycerol.