# Glucose to Glucose-6-phosphate

Tags: biochemistry

What does actually occur- ATP is hydrolysed and esterification between glucose and HPO4^2- (formed as a result of hydrolysis) take place to form Glucose-6-phosphate or nucleophilic attack of O- of glucose on ATP leads to formation of ADP and Glucose-6-phosphate?

Comment: I think since this is about chemical reaction mechanisms, it will be better suited at chemistry.stackexchange.

Comment: Duplicate of http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/10938/3340